# Is the Broker able to Block unwanted topic spammers?

Tags: erlang, mqtt, iot, broker

I have a MQTT environment like this:

[image]

there is One (gray) sensor and one Observer that are related by the topic **room/temp**, so far so good, sensor can publish and the Observer can get the info as it should.

the Issue I have is now: I need to block IN THE BROKER that a 2nd undesired client comes(the orange one),and start to publish into the same topic, as far as I know, MQTT is loose coupled so that observer doesn't care who is pushing the temp values, but I find a security flawless when someone hack my environment and publish non sense triggering my alarms...

any suggestion?

am using eMQTTd by the way and according to [this](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/emqttd-docs/stable/emqttd-docs.pdf) there is nothing in the **etc/emqttd.config** file I can do to avoid that...

Thanks!

Comment: The emqttd doc lists a number of modules that will add authentication and acl support. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: Also topics​ should not start with a /

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience with Mosquitto but, from a quick read of the document linked, it looks like there are several ways you could achieve this.

I am unclear if you are talking about an incidental problem here--i.e. bad information is being accidentally sent--or if you are protecting against an active threat.

If you are concerned with incidental overwriting of a value, then the simple clientid solution on (pg. 38) would work.

But my impression is that it would still be transmitted in the clear and thus be of little use to you if you are facing an actual adversary (hacker etc.). If that is your concern simply setup SSL and remove all non-SSL listeners. (See pg. 24). That should limit all traffic to an encrypted channel. Then if you wish add password / user authentication (pg. 38) to complete the security.

Alternatively, depending on your configuration, you could block unapproved ip addresses at the firewall level (i.e. block access to the port that your broker is listening on to all addresses except for the temperature sensor) or using eMQTTd's built in ACL facility (pg. 25). That would be less secure than a full SSL setup but depending upon your needs it might be enough.